# How to debug Expo + Hermes + VSCode?

Tags: react-native, expo, vscode-debugger, react-native-hermes

I was using **VSCode** to debug my application but I needed to install **Reanimated 2** and after that it was no longer possible to debug in the same way I used to debug.

.vscode/launch.json:

[image: .vscode/launch.json]

The second configuration works but is without Hermes, which prevents me from debugging the application when he use Reanimated 2.

The first configuration (with Hermes) cannot connect to my packager, when starting debug mode it only shows these messages:

[image: hermes debug messages]

Remembering that I'm using Expo and before trying to debug I run the command to start the packager:

`$ expo start --dev-client -c`

Comment: I am facing the same issue when attaching to debugger, it seems to be able to catch the exception but all breakpoints don't work. Do you have any updates on this?

Comment: @fsevenm I couldn't solve the problem, since then I've been using flipper to debug react-native apps.

Comment: Right, feels like I need to start looking at the other alternative like flipper also. Thanks for the sharing.

Comment: This configuration worked for me - without specifying the port number. It's really hard to tell what went wrong with this info. It may be the wrong port or a bug or misconfiguration anywhere else in the stack.